# Why doesn't setSpan work after the screen rotates?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-activity

I made a minimal repro of what appears to be a bug in my code. Create an empty app and paste the following in:

```
<!-- content_main.xml -->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/main_editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// MainActivity.java

private static SpannableStringBuilder sText;

private EditText mEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (sText == null) {
        sText = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world!");
    }

    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_editText);
    mEditText.setEditableFactory(new Editable.Factory() {
        @Override
        public Editable newEditable(CharSequence source) {
            return (Editable) source;
        }
    });
    mEditText.setText(sText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    workLoop(0);
}

private void workLoop(final int index) {
    SpannableStringBuilder text = sText;
    if (index == text.length()) {
        return;
    }

    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            workLoop(index + 1);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

**Explanation:** This code will put the text `Hello, world!` in an EditText, then proceed to color each letter blue after 5-second intervals.

However, if I rotate the screen, causing the Activity to be destroyed/re-created, the text stops being colored. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens, because after rotation `Activity` calls `onRestoreInstanceState()` callback method and overrides value of `EditText`. You should add something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mEditText.setText(sText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
}
```

Also pay attention at this line:

```
uiThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        workLoop(index + 1);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Anonymous `Runnable` stay runned and references to old `MainActivity` instance after new instance of `MainActivity` created due to screen rotation. I recommend to clear `Handler`'s callbacks in `Activity.onDestroy()` method.

Comment: I cannot see why `workLoop()` won't do its job even after `onRestoreInstanceState()`. What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @azizbekian, It's do its job very fine, but after `onRestoreInstanceState()` `EditText` displays another "saved" value from previous cycle of `Activity`, but not `SpannableStringBuilder` assigned to `TextView` in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I understand that. The question I am asking is why won't `workLoop()` would take that value and apply mutation specified in runnable method? If I'm not mistaken, OP claims, that after orientation change nothing happens. But I expect the text still to be updated, because I see no reasons for the opposite.

Comment: `workLoop()` will continue to mutate value by reference `sText`, but inside `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState()`  to `TextView` will be assigned reference to another value, created when `Activity` restored its state from bundle and type of this value will not be `SpannableStringBuilder` but plain `Parcelable` type. When `Activity` restores value from bundle in fact it creates new instance of object wich looks like our object, but is not our object.

Comment: It should looks like OP described: "text stops being colored". We'll see snapshot of value of `SpannableStringBuilder` created before screen orientation was changed.

Comment: @fishbone Excellent answer, I just tried your code and it works. I think I get you now. You're saying that even though I call `setText(sText)` in `onCreate()`, `onRestoreInstanceState()` which is called after `onCreate()` calls `setText()` with a cloned `SpannableStringBuilder`, correct?

Comment: Exactly. It's very interesting question. I think, only guy under the neurostimulants like in "limitless" can reach the answer with his mind. I had to use the debugger.